Issue making conditional renderCustomView on react native gifted chat
I am trying to add a touchable button to my chatbot bubble on react-native gifted chat. I created a conditional (isSchedule) to determine which messages the button should show up in. The touchable button does appear in the correct bot message, but for some reason, it also appears in my user message above.
My texts with the chatbot. As you can see, it adds the button to not only my message but the message above as well. It should only appear with the bot message.
This is my touchable button code.
const pressButton = useCallback(() => 
      {
        if (isSchedule && scheduleMessage.trim()===) {
          return (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={pressedMessage}>
            <LinearGradient
              colors={['purple','white']}
              style={styles.gradientButton}
              start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
              end={{x: 1, y: 0}}  
            >
              <Text>Press this to add to calendar!</Text>
            </LinearGradient>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }
    }, [messages]
  );

This is my gifted chat code.
<GiftedChat
            messages={messages}
            showAvatarForEveryMessage={true}
            onSend={messages=> onSend(messages)}
            placeholder="Type your message..."
            renderBubble={renderBubble}
            user={{
              _id: auth()?.currentUser?.uid!,
            }} 
            renderCustomView={pressButton}
            isCustomViewBottom={true}
          />

try {
        const response = ...
        if (response) {
          const botMessage = {
            _id: ...,
            text: response.data.reply.trim(),
            createdAt: new Date(),
            user: {
              _id: 1,
              name: 'Chatbot',
              avatar: 'https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/robot-icon-bot-sign-design-chatbot-symbol-concept-voice-support-service-bot-online-support-bot-vector-stock-illustration_100456-34.jpg'
            },
            pending: true
          }
          

          if (response.data.reply.substring(0, 8).toLowerCase() == "schedule") {
            setIsSchedule(true);
            setScheduleMessage(response.data.reply);
          } else {
            setIsSchedule(false);
          }
          botSend([botMessage]);
          
          
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in sending message: " + error);
      }
    };

Please let me know how I can use the touchable button only on the specific bot-message without it being added to user messages. My guess is the problem has something to do with the re-rendering and updating of states. I already tried using renderBubble instead of customRenderView. I also used different conditionals such as
if (messages[0].user._id == 1) and that didn't work.
